# Why am I getting a response from the wrong API endpoint?

Tags: python, flask

I am following this [tutorial](https://pyliaorachel.github.io/blog/tech/system/2017/07/07/flask-app-with-gunicorn-on-nginx-server-upon-aws-ec2-linux.html) initially I was trying to get a response using postman with the url

`ec2-x-x-xxx-xx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/:8080`

but it would not return a response, so then I tried without the `/` at the end and it returned what I wanted, why is this happening as my flask route clearly has a `/` in it

My flask app looks like this

```
from flask import Flask

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="8080")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the parts of a URL is important.

The URL

`ec2-x-x-xxx-xx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/:8080`

Is going to attempt port 80, and look for a path `/:8080`.

`ec2-x-x-xxx-xx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/`

Will attempt port 8080 and look for a path `/`

Answer (score 0):

There are two different concepts that you are getting mixed up on here.

The line `@application.route("/")` defines the root of your site. That is the default entry point or path if you enter your site address in a browser without e.g `/about` at the end.

The address `ec2-x-x-xxx-xx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080` is a combination of the web server address and port, separated by a colon. You will not get a response if you alter this address. You could add a "/" after the 8080 to get to a particular page.